# One of Added subview is not visible in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my Application I am adding ALAlertBanner as subview to self.view. Initially it is showing fine. But when I redirect to another view and come back to same view then ALAlertBanner is not showing even it is sub viewed and all the frames are in correct co ordinates...!

Here is the Log for the self.view subviews. This is **displaying Banner**

```
2015-04-22 15:21:31.948 @@@@@@@@@@View Subviews are:(
    "<UIImageView: 0x7fdbf079d160; frame = (0 20; 1034 768); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdbf07194a0>>",
    "<UINavigationBar: 0x7fdbf0764f10; frame = (0 20; 1024 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fdbf0778de0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdbf0764e00>>",
    "<reviewSlideShow: 0x7fdbf0779540; frame = (0 64; 1024 660); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdbf0779a10>>",
    "<UIButton: 0x7fdbf0761b90; frame = (0 724; 1024 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+RM+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdbf0761360>>",
    "<UIButton: 0x7fdbf048fad0; frame = (0 349; 90 90); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdbf048f3d0>>",
    "<UIButton: 0x7fdbf0517240; frame = (934 349; 90 90); opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdbf05176e0>>",
    "<UIView: 0x7fdbf0779e40; frame = (105 166; 814 456); hidden = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdbf077a150>>",
    "<ALAlertBanner: 0x7fdbf07ab370; frame = {{0, 716}, {1024, 130}}; style = ALAlertBannerStyleSuccess; position = ALAlertBannerPositionBottom; superview = <UIView: 0x7fdbf079d050>"
)
```

**Not Displaying the Banner** with below Log

```
2015-04-22 15:22:47.437 @@@@@@@@@@View Subviews are:(
    "<UIImageView: 0x7fdbf2a96340; frame = (0 20; 1034 768); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdbf2a96480>>",
    "<UINavigationBar: 0x7fdbf29be040; frame = (0 20; 1024 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fdbf2a146a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdbf2a1bbd0>>",
    "<reviewSlideShow: 0x7fdbf2a606d0; frame = (0 64; 1024 660); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdbf293f400>>",
    "<UIButton: 0x7fdbf2a90f50; frame = (0 724; 1024 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+RM+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdbf04919e0>>",
    "<UIButton: 0x7fdbf2a90d30; frame = (0 349; 90 90); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdbf04b1500>>",
    "<UIButton: 0x7fdbf2a90b10; frame = (934 349; 90 90); opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdbf29202a0>>",
    "<UIView: 0x7fdbf04f66f0; frame = (105 166; 814 456); hidden = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fdbf04f6800>>",
    "<ALAlertBanner: 0x7fdbf2aa40f0; frame = {{0, 716}, {1024, 130}}; style = ALAlertBannerStyleSuccess; position = ALAlertBannerPositionBottom; superview = <UIView: 0x7fdbf2a96210>"
)
```

Code where I am adding Subview of ALAlertBanner to view

```
ALAlertBannerPosition position = ALAlertBannerPositionBottom;
//ALAlertBannerStyle randomStyle = (ALAlertBannerStyle)(arc4random_uniform(4));


for (id view in self.view.subviews) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[ALAlertBanner class]])
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

ALAlertBanner *banner = [ALAlertBanner alertBannerForView:self.view style:ALAlertBannerStyleSuccess position:position title:nil subtitle:nil tappedBlock:^(ALAlertBanner *alertBanner) {
    NSLog(@"@@@@@@@Banner tapped@@@@@@!");
    [alertBanner hide];
}];
banner.secondsToShow = self.secondsToShow;
banner.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
banner.showAnimationDuration = self.showAnimationDuration;
banner.hideAnimationDuration = self.hideAnimationDuration;
[banner show];

NSLog(@"@@@@@@@@@@View Subviews are:%@",self.view.subviews);
```

I am not able to recognize what goes wrong..

Please give suggestions that where I am going wrong..

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: Where are you placing the code to add the subview?

Comment: It is adding as subview using this line of code [ALAlertBanner alertBannerForView:self.view...!

Comment: Yes, I see that code. But what is the context? Where are you placing that block of code? `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `init`?

Comment: I am placing in a method and calling that method using NSTimer..! It will call for every specific seconds of time..!

Comment: Timer is initiated at ViewWillAppear..! method.

Comment: move that Timer to viewdidload from viewwillappear

Comment: I am calling in ViewDidLoad too..As per conditions...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overcome this by using TSMessage

https://github.com/KrauseFx/TSMessages

As I am facing above issue with ALAlertBanner..